# Does an Observable get handled differently in Lambda than a Promise?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, rxjs, nestjs

We're using the NestJS CQRS package in our application. This package allows us to create 'sagas' by generating RxJS Observables that trigger various background tasks.

We noticed however when running the application on AWS Lambda, that the function finishes before the background tasks do.

Does an Observable get handled differently in Lambda than a Promise?

```js
@Saga()
aggregateCreated = (events$: Observable<any>): Observable<AggregateCommand> => {
        return events$.pipe(
            ofType(AggregateCreatedEvent),
            map(async (event: AggregateCreatedEvent) => {

                const result = this.queueService.sendMessage(
                    "http://XXXXXXX", { test: "MessageContent });

                await Promise.all([result]);
                return;
            }),
            flatMap(c => c)
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you share more code that helps your lambda operate locally vs. online? I know you mentioned in different post that this worked locally but not when deployed, and that might help me hone in on an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The API of an `Observable` and `Promise` are very different, and I've yet to come by any documentation that supports the return of an `Observable` in an AWS Lambda function.

---

Some additional thoughts: The output of a `@nestjs/cqrs` Saga is an Observable of a command. The module subscribes to the Observable and executes the new command via the `CommandBus`.

With my understanding of AWS Lambda functions and the `@nestjs/cqrs` module, I don't believe you'd be able to return an `Observable`, let alone a `Promise`, from a `@Saga`.